# Binding the value property of an input to an attribute

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I try to create my own custom DOM elements with Web Components (with validation and server communication). I am following the tutorial on the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

```
    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
  }
```

I am able to receive the change of an attribute. But if I have for example a textbox, where the value gets changed. How do I bind the value of the textbox to the attribute? Is this even a good way to do it?

This is my code:

```
'use strict';

class PopUpInfo extends HTMLElement {

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['value'];
    }
    constructor() {
      // Always call super first in constructor
      super();

      // write element functionality in here

    var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});
    console.log("Created");
    let tbName = document.createElement("input");
    shadow.appendChild(tbName);
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
      }
  }
  customElements.define('popup-info', PopUpInfo);
```

Later on, I would like to add multiple html controls to "PopUpInfo". The name would be later somthing like "Controlunit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take the attribute, or a property and pass that value into the inner DOM. There is no "binding" unless you are using a framework. If you want to use LitElement or other things then you get binding. Personally I see those frameworks as a huge amount of overhead.

But look at this example:

```js
class PopUpInfo extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['value'];
  }
  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super();

    // write element functionality in here

    var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    let textEl = document.createElement("input");
    shadow.appendChild(textEl);
    
    // Set attribute to value of inner element `.value`
    textEl.addEventListener('input', (evt) => {
      this.setAttribute('value', textEl.value);
    });
  }
  
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log(`attributeChangedCallback(${name}, ${oldValue}, ${newValue})`);
    if (oldValue !== newValue) {
      this.value = newValue;
    }
  }
  
  get value() {
    let textEl = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("input");
    return textEl.value;
  }
        
  set value(newValue) {
    console.log(`set value(${newValue})`);
    let textEl = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("input");
    if (newValue == null) { // check for null and undefined           textEl.value = '';
    }
    else {
      textEl.value = newValue;
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('popup-info', PopUpInfo);
```

```html
<popup-info value="my info"></popup-info>
```

First: Since you are only watching *one* attribute your `attributeChangedCallback` function only needs to see if `oldValue` and `newValue` are different. If they are not different then there is nothing to do. If they are different they you use `newValue`.

In my example I am passing the attribute's value on to the property called `value`.

In the property setter I check to see if the value is `null` or `undefined` (Using double equals for `null` (`x == null`) does just that. If it is `null` or `undefined` then we set `value` of the inner `<input>` element to an empty string. If it is not `null` or `undefined` then we set `value` of the inner `<input>` element to whatever was sent in.

The property getter just reads the `value` of the inner `<input>` element and returns that.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. My goal was to create a solution without a framework, since I only need little functionality (and also for educational purposes). 
If I want to go the other way around (textEl.value -> value atttribute) I need to register a change event or?

Comment: Basically, yes. I change the code to include that functionality. But be aware that this is not how the default `<input>` tag works. Make sure you really want it to work like this.

Comment: Thank you again.
My goal was to get control of the process when the value of a textbox gets changed. All inside a web Component to get rid of the validation code in my main js file.

Comment: So maybe I do not need to deal with any attributes at all? Just with the value itself via events?

Comment: Then my example should work well. It is highly suggested to now use the `'input'` event instead of `'change'` since `'change'` normally only happens on blur and `'input'` happens for all changes to the value: https://javascript.info/events-change-input

Comment: If all you are after is a set of validation around an input then, no, you may not need the attribute. The properties should be sufficient. **But** be aware that currently input files in the shadow-DOM of custom elements can not participate in a standard form submission. So if this is to be part of a standard form, then either do not use shadow-DOM or realize that you need to find another solution.

Comment: It will be part of a Single Page Application. Do you know any ressource where I can read about benefits of using attributes in certain scenarios?
Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Personally I only use attributes for two reasons. 1) Because I need to use CSS on the `:host` element and then I can use the attribute selector: `[attr="val"]` and 2) Because I am using a framework that only uses attributes, like AngularJS. In almost all other cases I would rather use properties since I can pass objects, functions or anything else into a property. Sorry, I am not exactly sure of any resource that talks about the benefits of attributes over properties.

Comment: No problem, you've helped more than enough. Have a great day!

Comment: What about if I want to have the old and new Value of the changed value in my validation routine? Isn't it handy to store the "old" value as an attribute?

Comment: You can do that, or you can just store it in an internal property.